# WPF Book-like application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, flowdocumentreader

I would like to develop a WPF application which behaves like a book. There would be two pages and the user would be able to edit it.

I cannot use a FlowDocumentReader since it is not user-editable. I have also thought about using a moving richtextbox depending on the page that has the focus (within a FlowDocument) but it does not have the page break behavior when the text is too long (I do not want a scroll bar) like the FlowDocumentReader has.

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RichTextBox Margin="5,42,5,5" Name="richTextBox1" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" />
    <RichTextBox Margin="5,42,5,5" Name="richTextBox2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
    <Button Content="NextPage" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Margin="0,12,4,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="90" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="PreviousPage" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,12,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Click="button2_Click" />
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,12,0,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Minimum="8" Maximum="25" Value="12" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Page> book = new List<Page>();
        int pageNumber = -2;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
                book.Add(new Page("This is page number "+i+"\n\nContent goes in here."));

            // open the book on first page
            button1_Click(null, null);

        }

        class Page
        {
            public Page(string text)
            {
                this.Text = text;
            }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }


        public void setTextToPage(ref RichTextBox page, string text)
        {
            // Create a FlowDocument to contain content for the RichTextBox.
            FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

            // Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument.
            myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(text)));

            page.Document = myFlowDoc;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (book.Count < (pageNumber + 4))
            {
                return;
            }

            pageNumber += 2;
            setTextToPage(ref richTextBox1, book[pageNumber].Text);
            setTextToPage(ref richTextBox2, book[pageNumber+1].Text);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pageNumber < 2)
                return;

            pageNumber -= 2;
            setTextToPage(ref richTextBox1, book[pageNumber].Text);
            setTextToPage(ref richTextBox2, book[pageNumber + 1].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'd like the text to be in another page when the number of lines becomes higher than the height of the richtextbox. I don't know if it's possible